# Duplicate Requests from a Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I go to a url such as

```
http://localhost:3000/test12
```

through a browser like Firefox (even in safe mode) or Chrome, I see a duplicate request in the log.  This happens both locally in development or on the web in production:

- Started GET "/test12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-30 18:02:29 -0500
- Processing by SharedController#test12 as HTML
- Started GET "/test12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-30 18:02:34 -0500
- Processing by SharedController#test12 as HTML

But when I curl that url, I don't see the duplicate request:

- Started GET "/test12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-30 18:04:39 -0500
- Processing by SharedController#test12 as * / *

Any suggestions for what might be happening?  This is Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.93.

Comment: Sounds like some kind of plugin, try hitting the url with all plugins disabled to see if it's the same behaviour ?

Comment: I tried Firefox in safe mode, but I still do see duplicate requests about 1 second apart.

Comment: Maybe some javascript on the page?

Comment: Show use the html for the page.  My guess is there is maybe a a broken image link or javascript link/action  that the browser is parsing/trying to use, hence you don't see it in curl as it doesn't fetch related resources.. .

Comment: Yes, it seems to be related to the view-- thanks for the suggestions.  I'm going to test that now...

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes, it was a resource being loaded in the header.  It turns out it was a missing URL in some CSS for "background-image: url();"  If you or Doon add your comment as an answer, then I'll accept it as the solution.

Comment: @Doon, as mentioned in the previous comment, if either you or FrederickCheung adds your comment as an answer, then I'll accept the first one as the solution.

Comment: you can just post your own solution,  saying you figured it out with help from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the commenters mentioned that the problem might be with a resource such as an image or JS that is not successfully loading.

After testing, I found that it was indeed some CSS that was missing a URL: "background-image: url();".

Answer (score 0):

Since you could have an addon making those requests, restart Firefox without addons:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion-- good thinking.  I tried Firefox in safe mode, but I still do see duplicate requests about 1 second apart.